# I cannot change a video using MediaPlayer without reseting

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer

I am working with streaming video and I want to change from one source to another dinamically.
First I set the video uri to the VideoView

```
view.setVideoURI(myUri);
```

And I know that I am capable of changing it afterwards by doing (this is in onPrepare method but it could go somewhere else where I have access to the MediaPlayer).

```
@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        Uri newUri = getOtherUri();
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), newUri);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    }
```

The thing is, I want to change the source without reseting the mediaPlayer (I do not want to disturb the user).
I tried to create a new VideoView with the new Uri and then change one object for the other, and likewise with the media player. However, none of that seems to work. 
Is it possible to replace a video while it is playing in Android?
Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to reset the video without using `mediaplayer.stopPlayback()` or `mediaplayer.reset`. The reason is that; the previous object of the mediaplayer has to be released before you can play other video .

`I want to change the source without reseting the mediaPlayer (I do not want to disturb the user).`

Well, this cannot be achieved as the mediaplayer has to be reset. So there will be lag while changing videos. And to satisfy you, you can see these behavior in any videoplayer app like `youtube` or `mxplayer`.

So the only thing you can do is to show `progressbar` while loading or changing video.

Hope it helps. Cheeers.:)